# How to choice activity to open when notification clicked

Tags: android, notifications

Is there way to choice the activity to start just in moment of clicking notification?
I can use `setContentIntent` when I build notification. But being once shown it seems not possible to set or change content intent in moment of click...

Answer (score 0):

The work-around I would suggest is to direct the *setContentIntent* to a simple activity , which handles you specific cases in the *onCreate()* with the needed intent of your choice.

Comment: You right, it's a solution, and I use it :) Just want to simplify logic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOURACTIVITY.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: `FLAG_ONE_SHOT` is not helps here. I need to choice, for example, between `YOURACTIVITY1.class` and `YOURACTIVITY2.class`.

Comment: put initialization of intent into if statement